# How to filter metadata w/ where condition such as str.contains() in Chroma DB or langchain chromadb

Tags: metadata, langchain, chromadb

I am using `Chroma`
`from langchain.vectorstores import Chroma`
According to [chroma's doc](https://docs.trychroma.com/usage-guide), it only allows `$eq`, `$in` etc for metadata filed.

```
My case has metadata as:
 {'source': 'itemIdABC__*__2023-08-10'}
 {'source': 'itemIdABC__*__2023-10-10'}
 {'source': 'itemIdXYZ__*__2023-08-10'}
 {'source': 'itemIdMNK__*__2023-08-10'}
```

I want to limit my retrieval to only slices w/ itemIdABC, but in langchain Chroma I can't do things like "contains", "itemIdABC"

to get both of slices of "itemIdABC" related chunk of doc, I can only do:

- Option1: create itemid__*__date metadata, then filter list out all dates available w/ `$in`. This requires a creating a dynamic list of all_dates available for the items
- Option2: add ACTIVITY_DATE_*_date at the beginning of each slice of doc chunk. then use Where clause to filter doc content, I remember chromadb enables `$contain` in doc content search.
- Option3: set multiple keys("item, date" instead of "source" like above) in metadata definition, so that only search for one key

I am wondering besides the above options, is there any other walkthrough? the question behind question is why Chromadb does not allow "contains" operation in metadata?

Comment: I am using option3 now, pretty easy:
```
 {'item': 'itemIdABC', 'date':'2023-08-10'}
 {'item': 'itemIdABC', 'date':'2023-10-10'}
```
so that pretty easy to search metadata through db created through langnchain's Chroma
db.similarity_search(question, k=5, filter={'item': 'itemIdABC'})